# Indexing into Controls Collection on Tab Control

Tags: c#, winforms, tabs, panel, tabcontrol

I have a C# Forms tab application. Each TabPage has a menu on the left (Outlook style navigation panel), and a Panel on the right for content.

If I want the content panel for tab page 0, how would I go about fetching it? I'm a bit stumped because I don't know how to index into the controls collection on a tab page. The following is underlined in red, so I believe its wrong.

```
Panel panel = tabControl.TabPages[0].Controls["Panel"];
```

EDIT: remove Window in Panel sub question. It will be moved to a separate question.

Sorry about the beginner questions. I'm a C/C++ guy with lots of MFC time, and C# UI is a bit frustrating at the moment.

Comment: wpf? silverlight? asp.net? winforms?

Comment: @Muad - You didn't have to `-1` the question for unclear context, you could just ask the OP to clarify that. The question is 100% valid.

Comment: Don't sweat the -1 (I'm not). I've found Stack Overflow is patrolled by Nazis at times. I just live with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach (Control control in tabControl1.TabPages[0].Controls)
{
    // if (control.Name == "panel1")
}
```

You can always call this recursively on `control.Controls` to find a control in any hierarchy. `control.Name` can be used to find your specific control.

You can't show a Form, inside a Panel. You could create Custom Control where you can add your functionality and add that control to a Panel.

Answer (score 1):

in order to create a new form for example you need to create a variable of what ever form that it is you want to create. 
example

```
Form2 frm2 = new Form2();
frm2.Show();
```

if you want to show that form in the panel then the panel would be the Owner keep in mind the difference between Owner and Parent 
please paste what ever code you have so far and we can suggest the necessary changes

Comment: In MFC, I usually deal with Windows. In this case, how can I have a Panel show a Window rather than a Form. (Another problem: how does one build a Window in C# - I can only find a new From from the Add menu).

Comment: C# does not like specifiying an owner: `Form f = new Form2(panel);` is displayed in red, so I believe its wrong.

Answer (score 1):

`Finally, how does one display a Window in a Panel?` - you don't want to do that. If you want a window and a panel to share a piece of UI functionality, create a user control with all the the functionality and then you can place it in a form or in a panel.

Comment: Thanks Andrey. Its not so much share functionality, its closer to layout the Window in its own form to keep things separated (tidy). Recall there is a menu control on the TabPage - which means the Panel gets quite messy if all menu items show up on one panel.

Answer (score 1):

A possibility to encapsulate complex UI content is to create a [`UserControl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.usercontrol%28v=VS.90%29.aspx). This way you can create a reusable piece of complex UI you can basically add as a "blob" inside a form.

The reason why

```
Panel panel = tabControl.TabPages[0].Controls["Panel"];
```

is underlined red is because the `Controls` collection returns a [`Control`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.aspx) which might be a `Panel` but also might be something else. So you need to cast it:

```
Panel panel = tabControl.TabPages[0].Controls["Panel"] as Panel;
if (panel != null)
{
     // got a panel here so do something
}
```

Also: MSDN has some good resources - you should make use of it.